# Automatically playing next audio file from collection view

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, sequence, avplayer, playback

I'm building audio book app.
I have play button inside my collection view cell where users see list of all mp3 files. When user presses this button (play button) - I'm sending data of track to my player class and music file starts to play. I'm using global variables to send track details to my player.

Here's my code:

```
extension ChapterDetailsViewController: AliaCellDelegate {

    func playAlia(cell: AliaCell) {
         NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "playAudio"), object: nil)
  }
}
```

I need to implement such functionality: When track comes to an end - automatically play next file from same list. For this, I have this method inside my player class, that informs me, when it has finished playing:

```
func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) { 
     print("Finished playing")
}
```

But I don't know how to call `func playAlia(cell: AliaCell)` inside `func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification)` in my player class and pass details of the next track from my collection view.

For now I have created only:
`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playNext), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "playNext"), object: nil)` but what should I do next?

Comment: take your next track name from tracks array and send to your player class

Comment: It sounds like overcomplicating things to use NotificationCenter for this. What class are you using to actually play the sound? If it provides a completionhandler, calling something like canister_exister sketches above should pretty much do it.

Comment: @GOR My player class is `class AudioPlayer: UIViewController { }`. Thing is, that this VC has container view, where navigation controller with all my other screens is embed in. So that the player is visible on every screen. I'm using NotificationCenter as it's simpler for me to implement and understand it.

Comment: what about to separate player UI and player logic?

Comment: @canister_exister Usually I would do so, but in this case it's UI very simple and built using storyboards, it takes only 20 rows of code in my file to describe it, so I didn't see any point in separating it when was making it. As for your advice - I'll try, I was thinking about calling `func playAlia(cell: AliaCell)`, but your idea seems more easier, thanks.

Comment: make func playAlia(trackName: String)

Comment: I will assume that you have some model/data source (an Array) of tracks that you use to display in the collection. You should use this source and design a method that accepts "index" which you use to grab "next" track from the array. Just keep track of "currentTrackIndex" and increment after previous finished.

Comment: @PeterPajchl thanks for your help. I have tried your solution and it works. Please write your answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to keep track of existing track within your source model. The example makes plenty of assumptions and is not it not complete.

```
struct Track {
    let url: URL
    let title: String
    let artist: String
}    

class AudioPlayer: UIViewController {
    var currentTrackIndex: Int = 0
    let tracks: [Track] = [Track(), Track(), Track()]
    let player: AVPlayer()

    // table view delegate for row selection
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
     didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // assuming single section
        currentTrackIndex = indexPath.row
        playTrack(at: currentTrackIndex)
    }

    func playTrack(at index: Int) {
        let nextTrack = tracks[index]
        let nextItem = AVPlayerItem(url: nextTrack.url)
        player.replaceCurrentItem(with: nextItem)
    }

    func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) { 
        // add logic to handle out of bounds index for array 
        currentTrackIndex += 1
        playTrack(at: currentTrackIndex)
    }

}
```